# How does jetstreams lead to formation of heat waves in Europe?

Tags: climate, geography, jet-stream

Jetstreams move at an altitude of roughly 6-9km above the sea level. Since, it is moving at such a great altitude how could it have possible impacts on the land? And how will jetstreams that flow at such a high altitude cause heat waves in regions below it?

Comment: https://www.iflscience.com/environment/omega-shaped-jet-stream-responsible-europe-s-heatwave/

Comment: @gansub "If this upper level(warm air from Southern Europe and North Africa being pulled North) feature coincides with high pressure at the surface with relatively low pressure to the east and west an omega block is formed." The article does not mention the factors that lead to the formation of Omega Block (Why a High Pressure on the surface, Low Pressure on east and west?). I suppose the role of jet stream in heat waves is dragging warm air from subtropic to further north.

Comment: A block forms at the 500 hPa surface not at jet stream level. The 200 hPa would have a corresponding ridge though. Usually a blocking pattern is preceded by a strong meridional southerly flow. I think your question would require ain depth answer and I do not have the time to answer it unfortunately.

Comment: Read about the preconditions for blocking here - https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469%282001%29058%3C0933%3APSPFTO%3E2.0.CO%3B2

Comment: vertical penetration is possible because of the vertical extent. A ratio of horizontal and vertical extent of the anomaly will decide whether a particular upper level phenomenon can influence the lower level.